# Is this relation symmetric, anti-symmetric or neither?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The relation R on the set ℤ is defined by the rule R = {(x,y) ∈ ℤ : xy+y is even}.

For  example: (5,3) ∈ ℤ, and (3,5)∈ ℤ, both would be even so this would be symmetric.

For a counterexample: (3,4) ∈ ℤ but (4,3) would not be an element of the set since 4(3)+3= 15, so this example would be anti-symmetric. Would that mean neither is the answer since it has symmetric and anti-symmetric examples?

Comment: I think you mean "(5,3) ∈ R, and (3,5)∈ R"

Comment: Also, in defining $R$ we should say $(x,y) \in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ or something equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

It is not symmetric because

$$(3,4)\in R \text{ but } (4,3)\notin R$$

it is not antisymmetric because

$$(2,4)\in R \text{ and } (4,2)\in R \text{ and } 2\ne 4$$

Comment: Simply put. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would mean that it is neither. You've found one counterexample pair $(5,3)$ which shows that the relation isn't antisymmetric and one pair $(4,3)$ which shows it isn't symmetric.

Don't think of a single pair like $(5,3)$ as symmetric and $(4,3)$ as antisymmetric. A whole relation can have such a property, but not a single pair (or a pair of pairs). A single pair can, however, disprove that a relation has such a property, like in this case.

Comment: The OP hasn't proved that the relation isn't antisymmetric.  It can be implied by the fact that $(3, 5) \in R$ and $(5, 3) \in R$, but $3\neq 5$, but neither the OP, nor you, showed explicitly that hence the relation is antisymmetric.

Comment: @amWhy $5R3$ and $3R5$ but $5\neq3$ doesn't disprove antisymmetry? (He means $\in R$, not $\in \Bbb Z$, presumably.) Have I missed something?

Comment: I don't see the OP nor you explicitly stating that the presence of $(3, 5), (5, 3) \in R$ means the relation is antisymmetric. Neither of you states the definition of antisymmetry, nor that this pair shows a violation because $3\neq 5$.  You did so in a comment. If you put your comment in your answer, I'll think more favorably on your answer.

Comment: @amWhy He uses non-conventional and not entirely correct terminology, but to me it's clearly there.

Comment: The OP suggests that because $(3, 4) \in R$ but not $(4, 3)$, that makes it antisymmetric.  You have not addressed this misunderstanding about what anit-symmetric means.

Comment: @amWhy Yes, I have. The OP thinks of a single pair (or a pair of pairs, really) as antisymmetric, and I do address that in my second paragraph.

Comment: I'm assuming anti-symmetric means that if for all a, b ∈ A, if a ≠ b and (a,b) ∈ R then (b,a) ∉ R and symmetric means they both are members of R. So (5,3), backwards and forwards (excuse the bad terminology) is even, so is symmetric, and (3,4) is even as part of R, but (b,a) or (4,3) is odd and is ∉ R, so this example is anti-symmetric. Having both symmetric and anti-symmetric properties  makes the relation neither right?

Comment: @happysaint $(5,3)$ isn't as much symmetric as it _disproves antisymmetry for $R$_. Similarly, $(4,3)$ isn't as much antisymmetric as it _disproves symmetry for $R$_. As I said in my answer, don't think about symmetry and antisymmetry as something a single pair has or doesn't have. They are properties that an _entire relation_ either has or doesn't have, and if it does have one of them (or both), then that is a promise that all of its pairs behave a certain way.

Comment: I see, in class we were going over arrow diagrams and how having both symmetric (bidirectional) and antisymmetric (unidirectional) arrows in a relation means it's neither, so I was thinking about it like that, but that's different than showing why